# Could a DIY 1 kW portable version of the military non-lethal microwave beam active denial system (ADS) be made?

Tags: microwave, high-frequency, wave, waveguide, magnetron

How would one create a portable 1 kW microwave emitter that projects out a 95 GHz beam to about 5 - 10 feet?  What kind of components would be required?

I recently came across [this fascinating video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzG4oEutPbA) of a military microwave emitting "beam gun" titled [active denial system (ADS) that essentially shoots out a 95 GHz non-lethal beam.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Denial_System)

I've seen DIY electronics YouTubers converting old microwaves into "microwave ray guns" that are extremely dangerous, [such as this one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80kDn4vit_w)

I was wondering what the feasibility would be for an electronics hobbyist to construct a DIY portable scaled down version of a safe non-lethal active denial system instead of the "lethal microwave experimental ray guns" you can find on YouTube. According to wikipedia, the rudimentary specs of the military's system say it is just a 95 GHz continuous high frequency beam. Are the specifications and technology really that simple or in your opinions is there more to it, like what kind of microwave is it - circularly polarized, or linear polarized, etc, or is it a sine wave beam or a square wave, etc. What would you all suspect the actual detailed specifications of how this thing works are? Finally, how simple or difficult or feasible would it be for a DIY electronics hobbyist to source parts and have the knowledge to build a portable 95 GHz emitting microwave gun to say 5 - 10 feet? Would this be a project that your well-versed stackexchange user could pull off? It seems that if people are able to convert old microwaves into beam guns, surely they could do the same purchase a transmitter that emits 95 GHz non-lethal beams instead? I'd imagine there would be a portable version on the market by now for military and law enforcement.

Comment: Non-lethal does not mean safe. I am not even talking about "less lethal". For example, a device that can permanently blind you but not kill you is still non-lethal. Non-lethality is a very low bar for safety.

Comment: 95GHz and DIY are an contradiction in it self IMHO. To design means to validate and to validate means to measure. Measuring 95GHz stuff requires instruments out of reach for every hobbiest. By far.

Comment: What you are missing is the power level.  The ADS uses 100 thousand watts.  The lower power system from Raytheon uses 30 thousand watts.  To cause pain and burns at even a few feet will require hundreds of watts if not thousands.  Besides the difficulty of building such a system, you would have to deal with the interference to licensed 95GHz users that your device would cause - in other words, the FCC will come knocking the first time you use it.

Comment: What about a 95 GHz emitter that draws about 1KW of power, same as your standard microwave.  I believe this would proportionally send out a beam effective to about 8 meters...would this be doable for a DIY hobbyist, in terms of finding a components that could produce a 95 GHz wave at 1kW?

Comment: The OP seems reluctant to explain what s/he is trying to achieve. Does anyone have any ideas / suspicions?

Comment: "Effective" at burning skin at 8m doesn't mean that the output hits a brick wall after that.  You will also recall that your standard microwave doesn't leak radiation since your skin doesn't get hot when you are near it.  According to the FCC (https://www.fcc.gov/file/21474/download), 95 GHz is allocated to radiolocation and radioastronomy.  I assume these operators would notice and not be pleased with your kW transmitter.  I further assume that the FCC would take a dim view of your use case.  The military gets to use their toys because they are the military.

Comment: Just curious, how would the FCC or such operators track down an individual with his own DIY microwave beam, would a 1KW beam produce enough of a signal for triangulation?

Comment: From what I can tell, the FCC doesn't currently have a robust method of locating transmitters in that frequency band.  They do, however, have robust working relationships with anyone who relies on those bands, i.e. the military and intelligence services.

Answer (score 1):

Building a suitable W-band high power (kW) microwave source is beyond the reach of most hobbyists. Generally they require high vacuums and a superconducting magnet for the gyrotron. There are other complex details (the electron injection) that would likely make it a lengthy and expensive project that could end in failure without a lot of specialized knowledge. For example, this one from a paper by [Kim](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10762-015-0221-1) et al.

[image]

Comment: what about a 1KW power device, 1kW is the same power as your standard microwave and would shoot out an effective 95 GHz beam to about 8 meters, would this be in the reach of a DIY hobbyist to accomplish and build as a project?

Comment: Yes, beyond the reach (not to mention inadvisable to build something intended to broil the skin and corneas of protestors).